# Showing the disjoint union topology is a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a set and suppose that for all $\alpha \in A$, we have the topological space $X_\alpha$. Consider the set which is the disjoint union
$$
X:=\coprod_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha.
$$
Let $\tau$ be the set 
$$
\tau=\{U \subseteq X: U \cap X_\alpha \in \tau_\alpha \text{ for all $\alpha \in A$}\},
$$
where $\tau_\alpha$ is the topology of $X_\alpha$.

How do I show that $X \in \tau$? I don't understand why I am having so much trouble showing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Normally  the disjoint union of topological spaces $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ is defined as: $$X:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\left(X_{\alpha}\times\{\alpha\}\right)$$and is accompanied by injections $\iota_{\alpha}:X_{\alpha}\to X$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\langle x,\alpha\rangle$.

Preassuming that this is the case collection $\tau$ must actually be defined as:$$\tau:=\{U\in\wp(X)\mid\iota_{\alpha}^{-1}(U)\in\tau_{\alpha}\text{ for all }\alpha\in A\}$$

Evidently $\iota_{\alpha}^{-1}(X)=X_{\alpha}\in\tau_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in A$, so that we can conclude that $X\in\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $\alpha$, we have $X \cap X_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha} \in \tau_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Oops I have been thinking of the disjoint unions incorrectly. Thank you.

Comment: If $X$ is the *disjoint union* then $X_{\alpha}$ is not necessarily a subset of $X$. Yes, $X$ does contain a natural copy of $X_{\alpha}$.

Comment: @drhab I am identifying $X_{\alpha}$ with the copy of it.

Comment: Of course you do. I had no doubts about that. See my comment as a mixture of caution and nitpicking.